# SharePoint Framework operating (SPFx)

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, sharepoint-framework

I asked some questions about SPFx few days ago. I still have questions in mind.

I used some development tools to create my first web-app with SPFx :

- Node.js
- Gulp
- Yeoman
- Typescript
- Visual Studio Code

My first web-app works well. In fact, I don't understand how the framework works. 
I shall like knowing :

- What is the role of Node.js ? In practice, what does it do ?
- What are interactions between my web-part page, Node.js and SharePoint ?
- How my web-part arrives directly built on my SharePoint workbench ?

I didn't find neither a schema to illustrate interactions between different elements of the architecture or explications.

Answer (score 0):

To get a better understanding, I would suggest watching some of the PNP videos provided on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLR9nK3mnD-OV-RPXQ3Lco845qoEy7VJoc). They provide great training on understanding the framework.

Also, check out the [Overview Docs](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) on the Office Dev Center.